# prenex normal equivalence challenges in math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

consider

[image]

these two following formula are prenex normal equivalence with the above formula? i think yes, but didn't have any idea to explain it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I give an answer without using provable equivalences on Enderton, page 121 and page 130.
Main formula is equivalent to
$$(\neg\exists x\varphi(x))\vee(\forall x\exists y\psi(x,y))$$
and this is also equivalent to
$$(\forall x\neg\varphi(x))\vee(\forall x\exists y\psi(x,y))$$
but we have:
$$\forall x\exists y\psi(x,y))\leftrightarrow\forall z\exists y\psi(z,y))$$
so Main formula is equivalent to
$$(\forall x\neg\varphi(x))\vee(\forall z\exists y\psi(z,y))$$
Since neither x is free in $\psi(z,y)$ nor y and z are free in $\neg\varphi(x)$. So we can move quantifiers on prefix of formula and thus we have:
$$(\forall z\forall x\exists y(\neg\varphi(x)\vee\psi(z,y)))\leftrightarrow(\forall x\forall z\exists y(\varphi(x)\rightarrow\psi(z,y)))$$
and both of them are prefix normal

Answer (score 0):

I'll use Enderton's system (see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd - 2001)).

We start with :

> $\exists x \varphi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y \psi(x,y)$;

the first step is to change the second bound $x$ to $z$, in order to avoid problems with "clashing" quantifiers :

> **(A)** -- $\exists x \varphi(x) \rightarrow \forall z \exists y \psi(z,y)$.

We need some provable equivalences; see Enderton, page 121 and page 130 :

> **(Q2A)** -- $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> **(Q2B)** -- $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> **(Q3A)** -- $\vdash (\forall x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> **(Q3B)** -- $\vdash (\exists x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

Starting from (A), we apply first (Q2A) with $\forall z$ to get :

$\forall z(\exists x \varphi(x) \rightarrow \exists y \psi(z,y))$,

then we apply (Q3B) with $\exists x$ to get :

$\forall z \forall x(\varphi(x) \rightarrow \exists y \psi(z,y))$,

and finally we apply (Q2B) with $\exists y$ to get :

$\forall z \forall x \exists y(\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi(z,y))$.

Of course : $\forall z \forall x \alpha \vdash \forall x \forall z \alpha$ [see Enderton, page 118]; thus, the last formula is equivalent to :

> **(B)** -- $\forall x \forall z \exists y(\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi(z,y))$.

Now we apply the following equivalence : $\vDash_{TAUT} (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \leftrightarrow (\lnot \alpha \lor \beta)$ to (B) to get :

$\forall x \forall z \exists y(\lnot \varphi(x) \lor \psi(z,y))$,

and again we "switch" the two initial quantifiers to get :

> **(C)** -- $\forall z \forall x \exists y(\lnot \varphi(x) \lor \psi(z,y))$.

Comment: i think (B) is not prenex normal equivalence but (C) is. am i right? because in (B) use ( -> ).

Comment: would you please answer my comment ?

Comment: @Michle Jordan - φ(x)→ψ(z,y) **IS** equivalent to ¬φ(x)∨ψ(z,y) and the leading strings of qauntifiers are "the same" because the "permutation" of the two $\forall$ does not affect the meaning of the formula.

Comment: Dear Mauro ALLEGRANZA, if we want to select one of the (B) or (C) which one seems be more correct?

Comment: @MichleJordan - both are correct; (B) is "more similar" to the original one, due to the presence of $\rightarrow$.